# Pry like debugger for Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, sidekiq-monitor

I've tried pry and remote-pry, but no luck. I'm familiar with logging, but I want to be able to step thru my code and look at variables.

Does anyone know of anything I can use to debug Sidekiq?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best thing I've come up with is this gem `gem 'pry-remote'` it works great and stops all processes from running. And it works like `pry` just put in `binding.remote_pry` and you've got a stopping point.

Answer (score 21):

Workers are designed to be trivial to run.  Put pry in your worker code and run it in the rails console.

```
> MyWorker.new.perform(some_args)
```

Comment: I have an instance where the timing of an async job is an issue and running it in the console does not give me the necessary environment to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use byebug but you have to require it inside the class definition of the job.
For instance,

```
class SomeJob < ActiveJob::Base
  require 'byebug'
  
  def perform(*args)
    byebug
  end
end
```

then in your rails console run

```
SomeJob.perform_now(*args)
```

This will cause a breakpoint to appear where ever you have byebug called with your typical byebug prompt inside your rails console.